# C#: Can classes that implement interfaces contain methods outside of interface?

Tags: c#, interface

pretty simple question. I know in java you can, but in C# can you?

Comment: Out of interest, what research did you perform before asking here? Options I'd have considered: 1) Just trying it. 2) Looking at classes in the framework, plenty of which have methods other than those specified in the interfaces they implement. 3) Reading the language spec.

Comment: i googled for a bit, didn't see anything that had what i was looking for

Comment: @theStig: And did you try it? Surely it's the work of about a minute to just try it for yourself...

Comment: Yes, i did try it myself. And it didn't work. That's why I'm here. my project is acting extremely odd.

Comment: @Jon: for some reason my compiler is forcing me to reference the folder in which the class is, even after i deleted the folder. i tried to rebuild the solution and it's still not working.

Comment: @theStig: Please edit the code you've got into the question, including the error message. That sounds extremely bizarre.

Comment: @theStig: Check your `namespace` line.

Answer (score 5):

Like:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Foo ();
}

class FooBar : IFoo
{
    void Foo () { }
    void Bar () { }
}
```

If that's your question, yes, you can.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

For future reference, there is plenty of very good documentation on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can.

Answer (score 2):

In C# (and most of .net), a class can inherit (extend) a single class, and implement any number of interfaces.  Classes can implement an interface and have methods that don't belong to the interface.  Consider the `IEnumerable` class, which `Array` implements, but Array has members that are not a part of `IEnumerable`, like its indexer  `array[0] = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Any reason as to why you would think otherwise?
You can have a class implemented multiple interfaces for a class. If C# didn't support methods outside of the interface... you wouldn't be able to do that.

```
interface A{
    void DoA();
}

interface B{
    void DoB();
}

class C: A, B
{
    void DoA();
    void DoB();
    void DoC();
}
```